# OpenGL and SDL '#version required and missing' but working in debug

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl

I'm fairly noobish with C++ so it's probably a bit too early to get into this sorta thing, but anyway. I've been working on setting up a simple triangle in OpenGL and SDL but I have some weird things happening already. The first thing is that when I compile it I get one of three errors:

```
Line 194: ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.

Line 156: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  #version required and missing. ERROR: 0:1: '<' : syntax error syntax error

Line 126: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  #version required and missing.
ERROR: 0:1: 'lour' : syntax error syntax error
```

Like literally I just repeatedly hit the build button and it seems completely random whether it displays one or the other of the messages. Ok, so that's weird but what's weirder is that when I run it in debug mode (i.e I put a breakpoint and step through everything) it works perfectly, for no apparent reason.

So, I've come to the conclusion that I've done something stupid with memory, but in any case here is the relevant code (ask if you want to see more):

**Read File Function**

```
std::string readFile(std::string name) {

    std::ifstream t1(name.c_str());

    if (t1.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Error loading stream" << "\n";
    }

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t1.rdbuf();
    std::string src = buffer.str();

    std::cout << src << std::endl;

    return src;

}
```

**Compile Shaders**

```
const char *vSource = readFile("vertexShader.gl").c_str();
// Read fragment shader
const char *fSource = readFile("fragmentShader.gl").c_str();

GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);

GLint isCompiled = 0;
glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE) { // ... Error stuff here...
```

N.B there's a fragment shader compiling bit which looks exactly the same. Lines 126 and 156 are in the error stuff part of the vertex and fragment shaders respectively.

**Link Shaders**

```
shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);
glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
glLinkProgram(shader_programme);


GLint isLinked = 0;
glGetProgramiv(shader_programme, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&isLinked);
if(isLinked == GL_FALSE) { // ... Error stuff ... }
glDetachShader(shader_programme, vs);
glDetachShader(shader_programme, fs);
```

You can see the shaders if you want but they work (as in the fragment shader shows the correct colour in debug mode) so I don' *think* that they are the problem.

I'm on OSX using SDL2, OpenGL v3.2, GLSL v1.50 and Xcode 4 (and yes I did the text file thing if you know what I mean).

Sorry for posting a lot of code - if anyone has any tips on how to debug memory leaks in Xcode that might help, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you throw away the strings as soon as you read them leading to the vSource referencing deleted memory (and undefined behavior), instead keep the sources as `std::string` while you need the `char*` to remain valid:

```
std::string vSource = readFile("vertexShader.gl");
char* vSourcecharp = vSource.c_str();
// Read fragment shader
std::string fSource = readFile("fragmentShader.gl");
char* fSourcecharp = fSource.c_str();


GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vSourcecharp, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);
```

Comment: It worked! I'm not entirely sure how, though. You say 'I throw away the strings'... through which line? I guess I don't know as much c++ as I ought to... :( Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3183526 readFile returns a temporary `std::string` you immediately call `c_str()` on it but after the line finishes executing the temporary is cleaned up (and the returned pointer becomes invalid).

Comment: I think I see... So if that `vSource` object was not a pointer then it would work? (excluding the gl part)

Comment: @user3183526: `readFile (...)` in your code creates a temporary C++ string; calling `c_str (...)` on it creates a C string (character array with a '\0' at the end) and returns a pointer to that array. The real problem is that the array it returns is *not* allocated in long-term memory (e.g. using `new`). The memory pointed to can be overwritten as soon as the object that created it is destroyed. You have to use it while the C++ string it belongs to exists or make a long-term copy using something like `strdup (...)`. If you use `strdup (...)` you have to remember to free the memory eventually.

Comment: @user3183526: ratchet freak's code creates a ***copy*** of the string returned by `readFile (...)` and that copy exists for as long as `std::string vSource` is in scope. You get the same benefits as `strdup (...)` but you don't have to manually free the memory, C++ does that for you when `vSource` goes out of scope.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman though it's easier to think: "if the temporary result needs to live longer than the statement then put it in a local  variable." And then remember that the validity of the `c_str` result is tied to the lifetime of the `string`.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Yeah, I was trying to show that since GL uses C strings, at some point that C++ string has to be represented as a pointer. `const char *vSource` is not even a pointer to an object as the OP's comment implies, but an array of characters. If that were `const char vSource` it would be a single letter ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ok, so any idea why in Debug mode the correct string was shown?

Comment: @user3183526 undefined behavior is undefined. in other words it may work as one would expect or it may cause demons to come out of your nose.

Comment: @user3183526: Debug builds tend to add extra run-time memory behavior to aid in debugging. On some platforms you get special bit patterns for allocated but unfilled memory in debug builds that you don't get in release or special bytes are added to the end of blocks of allocated memory to detect overruns. The idea is to help you identify memory problems, but sometimes the difference in behavior can create problems of its own :P Your debug build defines some behavior differently than release and is well within its rights to do so because there is no standard behavior for what you are doing.